# SQL Server AutoClose option

Tags: sql-server, database-design

Is AutoClose ON a bad option for a environment with over 15 thousand databases with the same structure?
I know that we should leave this OFF as best practices in 99.99% of the cases. So is it the one edge case that the feature is meant for?
 
What we should be aware of and also improve in a instance like this?

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve by turning it on?

Comment: Hey Erik, I was just wondering if it would be a good choice to leave it ON to save resource, and then improve performance? 
Let's considering that in a environment like this, only about 5% of them would be in use at any point in time.

Comment: If it's a predictable 5%, meaning databases are used for a short period of time, you should be archiving them. If it's an unpredictable 5%, the option does you no good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

15K databases on one instance of sql server - depending on the activity, overhead of maintenance, backup time, etc sounds to be an overkill.

You should instead spin up VMs on one powerful host machine and then balance out your databases on multiple VMs.

You are looking at a [wrong place for optimization - Auto-Close option](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-wrong-optimizations/#opt10) and you know that [what you are trying to do is not a good practice either](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/buckwoody/2009/06/24/sql-server-best-practices-autoclose-should-be-off/) !

[image]

Remember: [Auto-close is deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135094(v=sql.105).aspx), so one more reason to avoid it.

Seems like you should invest in reading - [Multi-Tenant Data Architecture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx)

Comment: Kin, thanks for those information that you provided.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a good article on the subject;](http://sqlmag.com/blog/worst-practice-allowing-autoclose-sql-server-databases)

Given the overhead involved in re-opening a database after it's been closed, I would say, no.  Do not enable it.
The more databases you have, the more this problem is exacerbated.

That being said, if there are some other circumstances that makes you think it should be enabled, please include those details.  As sp_BlitzErik asked, what are you trying to achieve?